# Kernel Restarting : The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Anaconda Jupyter Notebook, I successfully run my code previously but after I updated the anaconda navigator and conda for installing HARK software. The code does not work anymore. I read the previous questions about the same topic but the answers did not work in my case. I believe the error occurs during initializing the packages. Help would be highly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import autokeras as ak

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print(x_train.shape)  # (60000, 28, 28)
print(y_train.shape)  # (60000,)
print(y_train[:3])
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. This issue is not related to Tensorflow. What are all things that you tried so far? Can you share complete traceback to provide appropriate solution?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I figured out the problem. Many packages were updated in Anaconda but, not all of them were compatible with each other. So, I made a new environment and installed all the required packages again. After that, everything went as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Many packages were updated in Anaconda but, not all of them were
> compatible with each other. So, I made a new environment and installed
> all the required packages again. After that, everything went as
> expected. (paraphrased from Batoot)